# JS letter switching using charAt & Slice

Tags: javascript, pdf, getelementbyid, charat

I'm trying to show PDFs and have small thumbnails but once clicked the thumbnails change to the full pdf.  I did a tutorial and got it working, but i want to know how to guess how the letters are changing, i got it working but dont know why/how.

Small PDF (starting link) - www.wheelsforyou.com/542bXp.pdf

Larger PDF (when clicked, url changes to) - www.wheelsforyou.com/542nVy.pdf

### Here is the code

```
<script>
    var s='fEM'

    var y=document.getElementById('folder').src,

    z=y.lastIndexOf('/')+1,

    a=y.indexOf('.pdf')-3,

    r=y.slice(8,z)+'wheelsforyou.com_',

    i=y.slice(z,a)+s.charAt(1)+s.charAt(0)+s.charAt(2);

    document.getElementById('riy').src='http://r'+r+i+'.pdf';
</script>
```

Comment: What are `#folder` and `#riy`, some `<img>` tags? Please also post their markup.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is `<a href="large.pdf"><img src="preview.png"></a>`?